# Jmeter: session expired when sending cookies via post request

Tags: jmeter, session-cookies

I am trying to send a `POST` request using an expired cookie to get the session expired response. How do I get a cookie from login, save it as a variable and use it in another `http` request by posting the new cookie received from login?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please edit your question to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We need to know what steps you've taken, or what code you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it to work by using regex extractor post processor.
I sent a login post request with login details
Then I extracted the Session ID(sessID) from the Login response header and stored it in a variable using regex extractor.
in the other requests, I replaced the session id value with the variable ${sessID} created with regex extractor and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Normally JMeter's [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) should automatically handle cookies, if it doesn't - there is a problem with the cookie itself and you should raise an issue against your application.

If you are absolutely sure that the cookie is OK and JMeter should be properly processing it you can try the following workarounds:

1. Choose a less restrictive "Cookie policy", i.e. `Netscape` from the relevant dropdown

   [image]
2. Add the next line to *user.properties* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

   ```
   CookieManager.check.cookies=false
   ```

   More information: [HTTP Cookie Manager Advanced Usage - A Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/http-cookie-manager-advanced-usage-a-guide)
3. If above hints don't help - [enable debug logging](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/hints_and_tips.html#debug_logging) for the HTTP Cookie Manager and update your question with the relevant entries from the log file